# Problems with httpd.conf configuration and .htaccess for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, centos

I've a problem with a Wordpress Multisite. I've changed the hosting server (dedicated server): the main site works fine but the other site (in subfolder configuration) gives me a 404 error. Searching in the internet documentation, I've read that is necessary to change the AllowOverride directive in httpd.conf but when I change this from None to All (and then restart the Apache server) the entire site (main e subfolder's) gives back an Internal Server Error. I tried many different configuration with "main" directory and virtualhost directory but without succes.

I write here the code of http.con

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride None
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www.domain.com
<Directory /var/www/html/www.domain.com>
#AllowOverride All
#AllowOverride Fileinfo Options
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to make it works?

PS. Also if I change only AllowOverride from None to All in  (and no other changes) the page give an Internal Server Error.

Comment: And what does the apache **`error_log`** says when you change it to `AllowOverride All` and it gives you a `Internal Server Error`?

Comment: Nothing. In /var/log/httpd/error_log there are no messages referred to the Internal Server Error

Comment: Then you have something really wrong, because apache don't just give out 500 error without telling you why on the `error_log`. **Try updating your question with the last few error messages you have there.**

Comment: On error_log I only have some "File does not exist" error...but these errors are under control because I knwo that in some pages some images are missing.